# Error! Cannot create crash report” and “Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-1015-raspi (aarch64)” when I run apt-get

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, apt

When I type a command like `sudo apt-get install vlc` it says this

```
Loading new sysdig-0.26.4 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-1015-raspi
Building initial module for 5.4.0-1015-raspi
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/sysdig-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-1015-raspi (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/sysdig/0.26.4/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package sysdig-dkms (--configure):
 installed sysdig-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sysdig-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you tried to install/compile sysdig oss tool previously.

1. Do an `apt-get remove sysdig` (since it is currently unsupported and probably ported from the debian distro port to raspbian)
2. If you look in `/var/lib/dkms/remove sysdig*` (ko files etc)
3. `apt-get autoremove`
   do a reboot and attempt your vlc install again.

Useful detail link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416912/why-can-i-not-remove-this-dkms-module

Currently there is no specific support for OSS Sysdig on RPI (as an FYI)